# ggplot cumulative frequency with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumulative-frequency

I would like to construct cumulative count for two groups and reweight it to level 1.

I know how to plot density in this case:

```
my_df = data.frame(col_1 = sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                   col_2 = sample(seq(1,100,by=1), 1000, replace = TRUE))
my_df$col_1 <- as.factor(my_df$col_1)
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = col_2, group = col_1, col = col_1))+
  geom_density(position = 'dodge', size = 2)
```

Here is the plot:
[image: pdf]

However, if I try to plot `cumsum` I am getting the following picture:[image: cdf]

As you can see second line starts where first line ends level.

Is there fix for it? I can always try to do computations manually and plot it, but I wonder if there is ggplot solution? There are some solutions that I found on SO, but they do not involve scaling data to level 1.

Comment: is this what you want? `stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="line")` or try the `stat_ecdf()`

Comment: @Jimbou I tried: `ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = col_2,y = cumsum(..count..), group = col_1, col = col_1))+
  stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="line")`. It did not work: starts at 500. I also tried: `ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = col_2,y = cumsum(..count..), group = col_1, col = col_1))+
  stat_ecdf(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),geom="line")` also did not work. It returned: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'count' not found`

Comment: try `ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = col_2, group = col_1, col = col_1)) +stat_ecdf()`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By right, this has already been answered by [@Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4870695/roman) in the comments but just to make it clear and expand on that answer a little.

Create the data:

```
my_df = data.frame(col_1 = sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                   col_2 = sample(seq(1,100,by=1), 1000, replace = TRUE))
my_df$col_1 <- as.factor(my_df$col_1)
```

We can get cumulative counts using the `stat_ecdf()` function and to split this by group, simply use the `aes` variable `group`. Putting this together we get:

```
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = col_2, 
                         group = col_1, 
                         col = col_1)
       ) +stat_ecdf()
```

[image: Using stat_ecdf and group]

You can also change from the line to something akin to a distribution (filled area) by using `geom="ribbon"` and referencing the y cumulative value with:

```
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = col_2, 
                         group = col_1, 
                         fill = col_1)
       ) +stat_ecdf(aes(ymin=0, ymax=after_stat(y)),
                    geom="ribbon",alpha=0.2)
```

[image: Using stat_ecdf and group filled]

More on this in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643799/how-to-get-ggplot-ecdf-to-plot-with-filled-background)