# r ggplot plotly - fill area under the CDF curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve, r-plotly

Using ggplot2's *stat_ecdf( )* function, I have made a Cumulative Density Function plot. I am required to shade area under the CDF curve between two x-axis values and convert it to plotly output. Using the IRIS dataset, I have replicated the scenario with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

iris <- datasets::iris

iris <- iris[order(iris$Sepal.Length),]

(plot_1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
    stat_ecdf() +
    scale_x_reverse())

plot_1_plotly <- ggplotly(plot_1)
plot_1_plotly

(plot_2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) + 
    stat_ecdf(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ..y..), geom = "ribbon", alpha = 0.2, 
    fill = "blue") +
    stat_ecdf(geom="step") +
    scale_x_reverse())

plot_2_ggplotly <- ggplotly(plot_2)
plot_2_ggplotly
```

- **plot_1** produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdW8e.png), which is a normal CDF curve (not shaded)
- **plot_1_plotly** produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhyst.png), which is the plotly version (not shaded)
- **plot_2** produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUNnl.png), which is my attempt at getting the area under the curve shaded (with help from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643799/how-to-get-ggplot-ecdf-to-plot-with-filled-background))
- **plot_2_plotly** produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzNoi.png), which is the plotly version of plot_2

**Question 1:** In plot_2 output, how do I restrict the shaded area between two x-axis values (say x = 6 and x = 7)?

**Question 2:** When I convert plot_2 to plotly output i.e plot_2_plotly, why does the shaded area get messed up as shown in the output? How to get back to original form?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue trying to shade a region of the CDF curve for an exponential survival function. Using `geom_polygon` I was able to find a solution for a line plot of the CDF.

```
# creating poisson distribution with mean of 15 and cumulative count/ proportion
cumulative_frequencies <- data.frame(person_id=1:100,  
                      num_active_days=rpois(10000, lambda=15)) %>% 
                      group_by(num_active_days) %>% summarise(num_people = n()) %>% 
                      arrange(num_active_days) %>% 
                      mutate(cum_frequency=cumsum(num_people),
                      rel_cumfreq = cum_frequency/sum(num_people))


# create cdf curve
p <- ggplot(cumulative_frequencies, aes(x=num_active_days, y=rel_cumfreq)) +  
   geom_line() + 
   xlab("Time") + 
   ylab("Cumulative Density")  + theme_classic()
p
```

[image]

Then shading in the desired area under the curve using `geom_polygon`:

```
# minimum value of x for the area under the curve shading
x_start <- 15
x_end   <- 20

#Subset the data and add the coordinates to make it shade to y = 0
shade <- rbind(c(x_start,0), subset(cumulative_frequencies, num_active_days >= 
x_start & num_active_days <= x_end), c(x_end, 0))

# add shading to cdf curve
p + geom_polygon(data = shade, aes(num_active_days, rel_cumfreq))
```

[image]